# How to remove characters from a column not like specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a mssql environment, and i've uploaded a CSV file with first/lastnames/initials all in one column. The data is pretty messed up, format-wise, but it's all I have to work with. I need to extract the initials into a seperate column, and the format I need to extract is (example);

- JOHN B. SMITH
- SMITH JOHN B.
- B. JOHN SMITH

Simply said, the initial (B.) can be pretty much in any place. For some other names it's multiple letters seperated by dots (john b.l. smith, etc). What's the best way to take these values (just initials) into a seperate column?
Regards

Comment: Have someone go through the CSV data and fix it.

Comment: *The data is pretty messed up* - you should start with getting it corrected first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which works for initials of any length, and in any position.  The trick is to operate on the string in *reverse*, and find the position of the dot, and also the position of the first space which occurs after that dot.  To handle the edge case of an initial beginning the entire name, I add artificial spaces on the front and end of the name strings.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'JOHN B. SMITH' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SMITH JOHN B.' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B. JOHN SMITH' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'HARRY BP. POTTER' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AB. CHARLES ROGERS' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JOHN DENNIS HRM.'
),
newTable AS (
    SELECT
        name AS orig_name,                     -- original name
        REVERSE(' ' + name + ' ') AS rev_name  -- reverse name, WS padded at start/end
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    orig_name AS name,
    CASE WHEN orig_name LIKE '%.%'
         THEN
             REVERSE(SUBSTRING(rev_name,
                               CHARINDEX('.', rev_name) + 1,
                               CHARINDEX(' ', rev_name, CHARINDEX('.', rev_name)) -
                                   CHARINDEX('.', rev_name) - 1))
         ELSE 'NA' END AS initial
FROM newTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I tried running this on my db, and got an error on this value:
Q.B. Jansvill

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. 
Am i missing something?

Comment: Question: Does every record in your data have a name with an initial?  If not, this could explain why my answer is failing.  There is a simple fix, but before I put that in, let me know about your data.

Comment: Hi Tim, not every record has it, so I added a clause that checks if the value has a '.'. Now the statement works, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @stunnie I changed the query to use a `CASE` expression which will either print the initial, if the name has one, or will print `NA`, if one isn't there.  This lets you keep all your data, whereas a `WHERE` clause would not.

Comment: Please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
  ('JOHN B. SMITH'),
  ('SMITH JOHN B.'),
  ('B. JOHN SMITH')

  SELECT *, SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('.',Name)-1,1) INI 
  FROM @T
```

Result

```
Name                 INI
-------------------- ----
JOHN B. SMITH        B
SMITH JOHN B.        B
B. JOHN SMITH        B
```

Comment: This assumes the initial is always one character, which it might not be.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes it takes one character only.